# MySQL Join from a Rails Application Slow

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, join

I have a Rails application where I am executing a join statement via the following code:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT t1.`id` FROM `person` as t1 
      JOIN 'person_temp' as t2 
      on t1.`date` = t2.`date` 
      and t1.`name` = t2.`name` 
      and t1.`country_id`= t2.`country_id`")
```

In table_1 I have 100,000 records that should match in the `temp_model.table_name`. In other words the join should return 100,000 records. However, when I execute the query it just hangs, and seems to take forever. I thought it was the lack of indexes on the temp_model so I added indexes and it still is slow. I have indexes now on both tables for each of the columns I am trying to join on.

The schema looks like the following for the person table:

```
create_table "person", :force => true do |t|
    t.date     "date"
    t.string   "name"
    t.decimal  "amount",             :precision => 10, :scale => 2
    t.datetime "created_at",                                       :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                       :null => false
    t.integer  "country_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "person", ["name"], :name => "index_person_on_name"
  add_index "person", ["date"], :name => "index_person_on_date"
  add_index "person", ["country_id"], :name => "index_person_on_country_id"
```

The temp table or 'person_temp' has all of the same columns and indexes.

The output of `explain SELECT t1.id FROM person as t1 JOIN 'person_temp' as t2 on t1.date = t2.date and t1.name = t2.name and t1.country_id = t2.country_id;` is the following:

```
SIMPLE
t1
index
UNIQUE,index_person_on_name,index_person_on_date,index_person_on_country_id
UNIQUE
777

99560
Using where; Using index
1
SIMPLE
t2
ref
date,name,country_id
date
4
development.t1.date
1
Using where
```

Any ideas on how to improve performance or in this case just make it work?

Comment: please provide the explain output of the query. Also it would be better if you removed the `#{temp_model.table_name}` and provide the real example, with the ActiveRecord models as well.

Comment: I addded the schema, not sure how the actual model would be very helpful.

Comment: post the output of  
`explain SELECT t1.id FROM person as t1 JOIN 'person_temp' as t2 on t1.date = t2.date and t1.name = t2.name and t1.country_id = t2.country_id;`

from your mysql console

Comment: Loading 100k records into Ruby through AR is going to be CPU and memory intensive - the problem may not be the query itself, but the translation into AR models causing excessive GC invocation. Have you tried looking at `find_each` or `find_in_batches`?

Comment: Also see [the AR guide on EXPLAIN](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#running-explain) if you aren't familiar with its usage.

Comment: Well, in this case I'm not using AR objects, it is all being executed via raw SQL. No AR objects are being created. And even if I run this query at the MySQL console it is still quite slow.